# Derangements basic practice question

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, intuition, stirling-numbers

practice questions not Homework

I have problems with this questions that I have answers for but cant understand how the answer was derived.

Q.1. In how many ways can the integer $1,2,3,...10$ be arranged in a line so that no even integer is in its natural position?

Answer) $10!-(5C1)9!+(5C2)8!......-(5C5)5!$ I am looking for some intuition as to why this and why isnt it just a $d_5$ (derangement of 5 numbers as we are dealing with 5 even numbers)

Comment: The logic behind the answer is precisely the same as the logic behind the formula for counting derangements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of derangements of five elements would tell you what order you were putting the even numbers in... but, not even derangements are enough to satisfy these conditions.

Consider, for instance, the ordering 10, 6, 8, 2, 4. This is a derangement of 2, 4, 6, 8, 10; however, where are we going to put the odd numbers? If you choose to put them in as 10, 1, 3, 5, 7, 6, 9, 8, 2, 4 then the result has an even integer (6) in natural position despite choosing the derangement!

So, instead, they start by counting the $10!$ ways to arrange the numbers with no restrictions, then work to subtract off the number of such arrangements which violate the condition.  Etc.

I don't think that your formula, as written, can possibly be correct; why would you be choosing 9 things out of 5?  And why would the next "logical" term by $\binom{5}{2}$?  Double-check that.

Comment: i have made the edit thanks for pointing that out but it was(5C1) not (5C2) or (5C9) as I had written. I am still reviewing your answer and understanding it.

Comment: so when they subtract $(5C1)9!$ from 10! why is $(5C2)*8!$ added again and so on and so forth

Comment: When you use $10!$, you have counted all arrangements in which one or more even number is in natural position.  So, you subtract off The $9!$ arrangements where 2 is in natural position, the $9!$ where 4 is in natural position, etc. This is a total of $\binom{5}{1}9!$. But, now you have subtracted off all arrangements where both 2 and 4 are in natural position (for instance) twice!  So, you have to add back those $8!$ arrangements; repeating this for all pairs, you get $\binom{5}{2}8!$. But now, you've added back in all arrangements with 2, 4, and 6 in natural position...

Comment: It is the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: thankyou that really helped